# Prevent pod deletion in kubernetes but allow scaling

Tags: kubernetes, policies

Is it possible to create a policy (kyverno?) where I would like to prevent deletion of pods with `kubectl` but allow the deployment/statefullset to be scaled down or up? I read somewhere, that a posibility would be to create a kyverno policy that would allow scaling down or up. But my question is, would that implicitly deny manual deletion?

I haven't tested this, but I will. Just wanted to know if there's a better way of doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't scale down without deleting Pods.  Kubernetes doesn't really have a distinction between a Pod being deleted by a manual `kubectl delete` operation vs. a controller making the same API request.

Comment: you should do that by rbac !
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/rbac-good-practices/